# Wordpress is removing some posts from the HTML tag where The Loop is placed. Why?

Tags: php, wordpress, html, wordpress-theming

I'm developing a child theme of [Onepress](https://br.wordpress.org/themes/onepress/). I need all posts displayed inside a container *div* that is inside the *main* tag. I did it in my code, but, some posts are rendered outside the *main* tag in the browser. It breaks the layout. Any help will be deeply apprecciated!

Here's the code in my **file**:

```
<div id="content" class="site-content">
    <?php onepress_breadcrumb(); ?>
    <div id="content-inside" class="container">
        <div id="primary" class="content-area">
            <main class="site-main" role="main">

                <div class="container">
                    <?php
                    if ( have_posts() ) : 
                        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                            <div class="container">
                                <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'custom' ); ?>
                            </div>
                        <?php endwhile; 
                        the_posts_navigation();
                    else : 
                        get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'none' ); 
                    endif; 
                ?>              
                </div>

            </main><!-- #main -->
        </div><!-- #primary -->

    </div><!--#content-inside -->
</div><!-- #content -->
```

The code in **custom template file**:

```
<article class="row entry-article col-sm-12 col-md-12 w-100" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class( array('list-article', 'clearfix') ); ?>>

<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3 thumb-custom-container">
    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_permalink() ); ?>">
        <?php
        if ( has_post_thumbnail( ) ) {
            the_post_thumbnail( 'onepress-blog-medium' );
        } else {
            echo '<img class="thumb-custom" alt="" src="'. get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/images/placholder2.png' .'">';
        }
        ?>
    </a>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <header class="entry-header col-sm-12">
                <?php /* the_title( sprintf( '<p><a href="%s" rel="bookmark">', esc_url( get_permalink() ) ), '</a></p>' ); */ ?>
                <?php 
                    $post_id = get_the_ID();
                    echo '<h2 class="entry-price">R$ ' . get_post_meta($post_id, 'real_state_price', true) . '</h2>';

                    $post_id = get_the_ID();
                    echo '<small class="entry-features">' 
                            . get_post_meta($post_id, 'real_state_size', true) . ' m², Square '  
                            . get_post_meta($post_id, 'real_state_square', true) . ', Number '
                            . get_post_meta($post_id, 'real_state_number', true) 
                        . '</small>';
                ?>
            </header><!-- .entry-header -->
            <div class="col-sm-12 entry-excerpt">
                    <?php
                        the_excerpt();
                    ?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12 entry-link">
                <button class="btn entry-btn-details" href="<?php echo esc_url( get_permalink($post_id) ); ?>">+</button>
                <span><a class="entry-read-more" href="<?php echo esc_url( get_permalink($post_id) ); ?>">
                    Read More
                </a></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- PICTURE FROM CATEGORIE IMAGES PLUGIN -->
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3">
        <div class="col-sm-12 entry-residencial">
            <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_permalink() ); ?>">
                <?php
                $residencial_terms = get_the_terms($post_id, 'residencials');
                foreach ($residencial_terms as $term) : ?>
                    <img src="<?php echo z_taxonomy_image_url($term->term_id); ?>" />
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12">

            <?php 
                // Teste para identificar a cidade e chamar o modal de contato correspondente
                $cities_terms = get_the_terms($post_id, 'city');
                if (!empty($cities_terms)) :
                    if (is_array($cities_terms)) :
                        foreach ($cities_terms as $term) :
                            $term_name = $term->name;
                            $city = $term_name == 'City01' ? 'firstModal' : 'secondModal';
                        endforeach;
                    else :
                        $city = $term;
                    endif;
                else :
                    $city = 'generalModal';
                endif;
            ?>

            <button type="button" class="btn entry-btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#<?php echo $city; ?>">
                Contact
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div><!-- entry content -->
```

And this is the code rendered in the **browser**:

```
<div id="content" class="site-content">
<?php onepress_breadcrumb(); ?>
    <div id="content-inside" class="container">
        <div id="primary" class="content-area">
            <main class="site-main search-page" role="main">

                <div class="container">

                    SOME POSTS HERE

                </div>

            </main><!-- #main -->

            <!-- OTHER POSTS ARE INCORRECTLY HERE -->
            <div class="container">

                 INCORRECTLY PLACED POSTS

            </div><!-- incorrectly placed posts -->

        </div><!-- #primary -->

    </div><!--#content-inside -->
</div><!-- #content -->
```

So, anyone have a clue about how to fix this bug?
Thank you, guys!

Comment: what does your custom template that is called within the loop look like?

Comment: @OrlandoP. I updated the post with the custom template code. There's a closing tag for article, but is showing up in this post - I don't know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it looks like you have some invalid HTML in your code.

So far I could find this inconsistency:

```
<div class="col-sm-12 entry-excerpt">
     <?php
          the_excerpt();
     ?>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ow! I miss it. And, apparently, it was the problem. Thanks for the help @andriusain !